# Wordpress insert NOW() in TIMESTAMP column returns all zeros

Tags: wordpress

I want to insert a TIMESTAMP into my column's TIMESTAMP column, but I always get all zeros.

Here is my insert:

```
$now = 'NOW()';

// insert the date into the db
 $wpdb->insert( 
    'wp_date', 
    array(
        'name' => $name,
        'date' => $now    
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s',
        '%s'
    ) 
); // end insert
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with [current_time](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time), like this (I think it is good alternative):

```
$now = current_time('mysql');

// insert the date into the db
 $wpdb->insert( 
    'wp_date', 
    array(
        'name' => $name,
        'date' => $now    
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s',
        '%s'
    ) 
); // end insert
```

So, current_time parameter "mysql" means that mysql timestamp format will be used.

Comment: This kind of works, but I wanted to get the time as if I had used NOW(). With this code, since I am GMT+2, I don't get the correct time. I guess I'll have to use a raw query, not such a big deai anyway. thanks

Comment: @OlliccaMindstorm please clarify, GMT+2 is correct time you want to get, and you can't get GMT+2 time with my solution, right?

Comment: @Johhny, that is correct IN MY CASE. But if YOU are GMT + 10, it should be GMT+ 10, because the user whose name is entered can be from any country / zone.

Answer (score 0):

The function **current_time('mysql');** returns the time of blog, NOT mysql server. To get the time of Mysql server do the following.

```
global $wpdb;
$row = $wpdb->get_row('SELECT now() as now');

// insert the date into the db
 $wpdb->insert( 
    'wp_date', 
    array(
        'name' => $name,
        'date' => $row->now    
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s',
        '%s'
    ) 
)
```

So it's like...

```
$mysql_time = $row->now;
$php_time = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
$blog_time = current_time('mysql');
```